# Compiling C to WebAssembly on the web

Tags: web, emscripten, webassembly

Tools like [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) / the [EmSDK](https://webassembly.org/getting-started/developers-guide/) can be used to compile different languages, especially C to WebAssembly binaries (.wasm). Websites such as [WebAssembly Studio](https://webassembly.studio/) use them to compile high level languages through a web interface on a server.

Have these or alternatives tools been ported to Javascript/WebAssembly such that they can be run on the web themselves?

My objective is to be able to compile C source to .wasm on the browser client, and then run it there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can compile LLVM into asm.js or WebAssembly and run it within the browser. Here’s an example:

https://kripken.github.io/llvm.js/demo.html